# Is it possible to provide seprate server for each user in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

I am getting error whenever i recompile my workflow package. 
to solve this error i have to bounce the server which is used among no of users. 
if it is possible to get separate server so i can bounce and test it without disturbing DBA/system admin.

Comment: What error do you get? In my opinion, shutting down the server is probably the worst way of solving problems. Perhaps you should put focus on finding a way to get rid of that kind of an error. Someone might give you advice, but - fortune teller is on vacation, while the rest of us have difficulties in solving problems we can't see. I'm just kidding about it, but I'm serious about asking you to describe what EXACTLY is going on.

Comment: Event Error Name: WFE_DISPATCH_GEN_ERR
Event Error Message: 3835: Error '-20002 - ORA-20002: 2018: Unable to generate the notification XML. Caused by: 2020: Error when getting notification content. Caused by: ORA-20002: 3240: Error '-4061 - ORA-04061: existing state of has been invalidated
ORA-04061: existing state of package "APPS.ATL_OARR_PCKG" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "APPS.ATL_OARR_PCKG"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APPS.ATL_OARR_PCKG"
' in 'PLSQL' API 'ATL_OARR_PCKG.GET_CUSTOM_NOTIF'

Comment: I got the issue.
oracle 10g does not allow global variables in package body.
so whenever workflow launches, existing package in invalidate.
so if you want to use global variables then you should declare in package specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha; it seems that you posted two questions for the same problem; this is [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354393/is-there-any-way-to-compile-only-one-particular-package-on-server/48357900#48357900).

As of your problem: Oracle says this:

```
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "APPS.ATL_OARR_PCKG" ' 
in 'PLSQL' API 'ATL_OARR_PCKG.GET_CUSTOM_NOTIF'
```

Why wouldn't you make sure that all objects, referenced by your package, exist before you compile it? What benefit do you see in having an invalid package? You can't use it anyway, you can't test it, you can't do anything.

Therefore, having yet another server most probably won't fix that problem, because I suspect that missing package (if that's what ATL_OARR_**PCKG** is) won't automagically appear on the new server.

Comment: NO! 
I was thinking in two different way to solve that problem.
I suspect that Oracle 10g does not support GLOBAL variables in package body as well specification.
when you recompile body or specification which contain global variables will throw this error
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:"APPS.ATL_OARR_PCKG" ' 
in 'PLSQL' API 'ATL_OARR_PCKG.GET_CUSTOM_NOTIF'

Comment: OK then, you got it, great! I'm glad you found the culprit.